# How does the Copenhagen interpretation support the Pauli-principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, pauli-exclusion-principle

In QM the Copenhagen interpretation states that there are behind the probalities no real values like spin-state. Now in the Pauli-principle electrons can't have both the same spin in the same 'orbit', so according to the Copenhagen there can be more than 2 electrons in the same 'orbit'?

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow how one follows from the other:

> According to the Copenhagen interpretation, physical systems generally do not have definite properties prior to being measured, and quantum mechanics can only predict the probabilities that measurements will produce certain results. The act of measurement affects the system, causing the set of probabilities to reduce to only one of the possible values immediately after the measurement. This feature is known as wave function collapse.

The P.E.P is a definite property, as far as I know, so the C.I. does not support it, or have anything to say about it. If fact, I think you could argue that the P.E.P does the reverse, leaving the C.I. in doubt.

But my answer is based on a very superficial understanding of the different intrerprations. I hope you get a better answer later.